# Install Appharbor Add-on through API

Tags: appharbor

After reading : http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api

I can do almost everything through APIs.

But how can I install/remove add-on through the API.

for example :
I want to install SQL nano for my instance through API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-ons are not yet officially part of the API, but it's very simple to just drive the web interface. You can see [how AppHarbify does that here](https://github.com/csainty/Apphbify/blob/master/Apphbify/Services/Impl/ApiService.cs#L65).